# OutputSteam is abstract

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream

as the title says, getting the error "outputsteam is abstract". I'm new to Java so not quite sure how to go about solving it. My program is trying to send an arraylist of connections over a socket to a client, using this code;

```
public void sendList(Socket clientSocket, ArrayList connections) throws IOException 
{
    OutputStream outputStream = new OutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true); 
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(connections);
    System.out.println("List sent");      
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 6):

The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong: You can't call a constructor on an abstract class, and instead will have to initiate one of the concrete subclasses of OutputStream. Perhaps a BufferedOutputStream that wraps your clientSocket OutputStream.

Why do you even have this line?

```
OutputStream outputStream = new OutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),
             true);
```

Why not simply use directly use the OutputStream from the clientSocket?

Comment: it was something I was instructed to put in :| how would I go about your method?

Comment: @horHAY: please post the actual word-for-word instruction. As for how to go about, I'd do away with that line.

Comment: its now; ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream())
oos.writeObject(connections);
oos.close(); - although im getting the error "ERROR: java.io.NotSerializableException: Server.ClientConnectionInfo"

Comment: If someone instructed you to put that in, they don't know what they're talking about. More probably you misunderstood. Your new problem should be asked in a new question.